# storage rules for only png images firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have the following code in storage rules , but I cannot get it to work right, I need to prevent storing items other than pngs in to storage ? , but it is erroring out.

```js
     // Add to storage     
      allow write:  
      if request.auth != null  // Authorized
      && request.auth.uid == userId  // Owner
      && request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024 // Uploaded item must be less than 1mb !
      && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*'); // only image !!
    //  && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.png'); // only PNG !!
```

Comment: Hey!  I was writing you an answer to your Redux question when you deleted it.  Here's what to do: https://codesandbox.io/s/thunk-dispatch-with-settimeout-tcbpdy?file=/src/store/index.ts  Can just `dispatch(sendExpiringMessage("Please select a client"))`

Comment: @LindaPaiste thanks sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with .png or .PNG. It checks if the filename ends with .png

```
// Add to storage     
      allow write:  
      if request.auth != null  // Authorized
      && request.auth.uid == userId  // Owner
      && request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024 // Uploaded item must be less than 1mb !
      && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*'); // only image !!
      && request.resource.name.matches(".*\\.png"); // only PNG !!
```